# Query for join multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database with a table `'costumers'` of columns `id`,`name`. I have a separate database with custom tables names that are in format `table_customer_id_1`, `table_customer_id_2`, ...n and columns `id`,`price`,`datetime` (the name of each table contains the id of each row in Table 'costumers')

What is the fastest way to query the table 'costumers' and get the customer name from table costumers and the latest order date of each table_customer_id_X?

Sorry about my English are not very good and I dont know if you can understand what i m asking for! :)

Comment: One of the best ways would be to use a join, as suggested by the title of your question... you should try that and come back with the query (and a bit of database design) if you don't manage to make it work...

Comment: So you have one table for each customer in a seperate database?

Comment: @Bartdude this what i m trying to do. I will give a shot.

Comment: @user3083310 Yes thats right

Comment: @George > I understand, but see [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for an explanation on how you're supposed to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this

```
select 
a.name, 
b.DateTime, 
c.datetime
from customer a
inner join tbl_customer_id1 b  on b.id=a.id
inner join tbl_customer_id2 c on c.id=a.id 
where a.name like '%Customer name%' 
order by b.datetime , c.datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Customers (id int, name varchar(10))
CREATE TABLE #Table_Customer_id_1 (id int, price decimal(18,2), datetimefield datetime)
CREATE TABLE #Table_Customer_id_2 (id int, price decimal(18,2), datetimefield datetime)
CREATE TABLE #Table_Customer_id_3 (id int, price decimal(18,2), datetimefield datetime)

INSERT INTO #Customers VALUES (1, 'Test1'), (2, 'Test2'), (3, 'Test3')

INSERT INTO #Table_Customer_id_1 VALUES 
  (1, 1.1, '2013-01-01'),
  (2, 1.2, '2013-01-02'),
  (3, 1.3, '2013-01-03'),
  (4, 1.4, '2013-01-04')

INSERT INTO #Table_Customer_id_2 VALUES 
  (1, 2.1, '2013-02-01'),
  (2, 2.2, '2013-02-02'),
  (3, 2.3, '2013-02-03'),
  (4, 2.4, '2013-02-04')

INSERT INTO #Table_Customer_id_3 VALUES 
  (1, 3.1, '2013-03-01'),
  (2, 3.2, '2013-03-02'),
  (3, 3.3, '2013-03-03'),
  (4, 3.4, '2013-03-04')

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

;WITH CTE AS(
  SELECT 'SELECT name, LastOrder FROM #Customers INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(datetimefield) AS
    LastOrder, ' + CONVERT(varchar(5),id) + ' AS CustID FROM #Table_Customer_id_' + 
    CONVERT(varchar(5),id) + ') Tab ON #Customers.id = Tab.CustID WHERE id = ' + 
    CONVERT(varchar(5),id) + '' AS SqlStatement FROM #Customers
)
SELECT @SQL = STUFF((SELECT ' UNION ALL ' + SqlStatement FROM CTE FOR XML PATH('')),1,11,'') 

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

--DROP TABLE #Customers
--DROP TABLE #Table_Customer_id_1
--DROP TABLE #Table_Customer_id_2
--DROP TABLE #Table_Customer_id_3
```